# How to split a string into multiple parts?

Tags: python, string, split

I have `f = imgString.split('medias/')[1] g = f.split('?')[0] print(g)` but I'd prefer it on one line. How can I split this string into multiple parts `'media/Clearance.png?sometexthere'` .Ideally I'd like just the Clearance.png. so if I was splitting it it'd be 'media/', 'Clearance.png' and '?sometexthere'

Comment: `import re; re.split('(media/|\?)', imgString)[2]`

Comment: Please mark the correct answer if your question was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```py
string = 'media/Clearance.png?sometexthere'
string.split("/")[1].split("?")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the same format you can use regex like this one :
`([a-zA-Z]*)\/(.*)\?([a-zA-Z]*)` and then with `re.group()` you can have all the parts of your string :)

 You can check it here [link](https://regex101.com/r/ukuRdn/1) !